# What is the sorting order of the names of custom filters?

Tags: support, sorting, custom-filters

I can see that alpha characters are sorted case-insensitively in ascending alphabetical order. What about other characters - how would they be sorted compared to alpha characters?

Comment: Well can't really use other characters, getting "Please only include ASCII characters.".

Comment: Anyway from quick testing, numbers are first, then letters - looks like simple alphabetical  sorting, no tweaks.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda [I'm definitely able to use other characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENe5o.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if there's going to be an answer for this that you like, at least not in terms of design or intention from our software.

The column that stores the name of your custom filter is:

```
column_name nvarchar(32) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

And the query that retrieves the list for the sidebar says:

```
ORDER BY column_name
```

This means the order you see is subject to the sorting rules SQL Server applies to that specific collation, which is typically based on the ASCII value of the first character (and then second, and third, and so on). When sorting strings that are *single characters*, this normally means they will appear in this order:

- symbols
- numbers
- lower case
- upper case

However, when you go beyond single-character strings, it can do odd things that you might not expect, and that are outside of our control. While anecdotally I've found that the above is still true when the string is *all* numbers, or all lower case, or all upper case, things start getting a little unpredictable when you have more than one character involving multiple symbols, different case, or a mix.

For example:

> [image: Example sorting]

- [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZpqnkjVq)

It seems like when the string starts with a symbol, the sorting falls to the next character. Notice how `'` is followed by `'-` and then `-` and then `-'`. When the symbol is followed by a *letter*, then the sorting moves down to be sorted by that letter, ignoring the symbol. Similarly, the case of the leading `z` is ignored in the last 3 (or even 6) rows.

That is never how I would have arranged them in my head or on paper. I won't pretend to understand it all, as that approaches requiring a PhD; I'll save it for [folks much smarter than me](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/175245/1186).

In the meantime, this kind of feels like if you don't want unpredictable or complex-rules-based sorting, stick to basic alphanumeric filter names, or at least alphanumeric characters at the *start* of the string. It all reminds me of a legendary interaction:

- **Patient**: *"Doctor, it hurts when I do {x}!"*
- **Doctor**: *"Ok, you should stop doing {x}!"*

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed what I was looking for. I wanted to put some filters "at the bottom" and tried a few characters like `_` or `+` or `|` but they didn't go after the alphanumerics. I also noticed that `-` was ignored when sorting, so `a`, is followed by `-b`, followed by `c`.  My "solution" was to just add `z` in front of the list name to move it down, however I looked around and found there was no clear explanation for how the sorting really works, hence the motivation for the question.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, we have a lot of sorting that relies on a single column (or on such a column first), so this would apply in those scenarios. We have a few places where there is no `ORDER BY`, so it's possible to see this symptom even by accident, if SQL Server chooses to use/sort by an index with a string as the leading key column.